# How to use the IntelliJ IDEA "Generate Signed APK Wizard" in PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, apk, pycharm, wizard

How to install/use the IntelliJ IDEA "Generate Signed APK Wizard" in PyCharm?
PyCharm lets me have a PhoneGap/Cordova project that generates apks. I'd like to use the IntelliJ IDEA Generate Signed APK Wizard inside PyCharm. Can this be done at this time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done at this time. The feature is part of the Android plugin, which depends on Java support in IntelliJ IDEA and other components such as the Gradle plugin, which are not available in PyCharm.